# is this listing correct or should I use other technique?

Tags: lists, enumerate

New to LaTex and to this Group.

I am currently trying to group together several answers from Algebra quiz.
In particular I have a question with lists: is this a correct way to list some points?

```
    \begin{enumerate}
\item[SV5]
$\forall$ \textbf{v} $\in$ \textbf{V} $\rightarrow$ 0 $\cdot$ \textbf{v} = 0
\item[SV6]
$\forall$ \textbf{v} $\in$ \textbf{V} $\rightarrow$ -1 $\cdot$ \textbf{v} = -\textbf{v}
\item[SV7]
$\forall$ $\lambda$ $\in$ $\mathbb{K}$ $\rightarrow$ $\lambda$ $\cdot$ 0 = 0
\item[SV8]
$\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ \textbackslash \{0\}  se  $\rightarrow \textbf{v} \in \textbf{V}$ e \textsl{$\lambda \cdot$ \textbf{v}}= 0 $\rightarrow$ \textbf{v} = 0
\end{enumerate}
```

Thanks for helping me out,
Alberto.

Comment: Welcome. Note that you are much much more likely to get help if you provide a full (but minimal) self contained example instead of sniplets like this. Then we don't have to make guesses in order for make a proper test file.

Comment: You're right. I beg everyone's pardon.
I'll be more accurate next time.

Answer (score 4):

You're typing formulas in a very wrong way.

From a mathematical point of view, your usage of arrows is wrong, too.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[SV5]
  $\forall\,\mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{V}$, $0 \cdot \mathbf{v} = 0$
\item[SV6]
  $\forall\, \mathbf{v}\in \mathbf{V}$, $(-1) \cdot \mathbf{v} = -\mathbf{v}$
\item[SV7]
  $\forall\,\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$, $\lambda \cdot 0 = 0$
\item[SV8]
  $\forall\, \lambda \in \mathbb{K}\setminus\{0\}$, se
  $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbf{V}$ e $\lambda \cdot \mathbf{v}= 0$ allora $\mathbf{v} = 0$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for commenting and correcting.
I appreciated it a lot.